# Validation for form not checking partly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel program that saves form data and uploads a few pictures. In the validation, there are two rules. The image is required and it has to be of image type (jpg, jpeg, png). However, the validation only checks for the filetype and does not check for 'required'. Even if there is no image, it allows the user to submit. Why?

```php
public function updateImages(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required',
        'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    ],
        [
            'image.*.image' => 'Format Error: Please uplaod image in a png or jpg format',
        ]);
    $item = Post::find($id);
    $existing_count = Photo::where('post', $item->id)->count();
    $countrequest = sizeof($request->file('image'));
    $count = $existing_count + $countrequest;
    if ($count >= 6) {
        return back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors(['Only 5 images can be uploaded!']);
    }
    $upload = $this->imageUpload($item, $request);

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Image Updated');
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `image.*`? Why not put all the validation under `image` ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply require with `image.*`. Eg.-

```
image.*' => 'require|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
```

Try this solution. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)

To create a form request class

```
php artisan make:request ImageUpdateRequest
```

Go to app/Http/Requests add the rules

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048'
    ];
}
```

On your controller

```
use App\Http\Request\ImageUpdateRequest;

public function updateImages(ImageUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $item = Post::find($id);
    $existing_count = Photo::where('post',$item->id)->count();
    $countrequest = sizeof($request->file('image'));
    $count= $existing_count+$countrequest;
    if ($count >= 6 ){
        return back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors(['Only 5 images can be uploaded!']);
    }
    $upload = $this->imageUpload($item, $request);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Image Updated');
}
```